# How React native converts require to UIImage?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, react-native

How do react-native converts require that returns a number to a source path (localhost:8081...) that can be used on UIImage?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide a [example] to clarify your question.